# Empty div with background color fitting the page's content

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm working on a website for a uni course and I've divided the page in 3 cols using bootstrap method. The center div is the one with the contents, while the left and right ones are empty with background color.
The only way I found working to make the background color go all the way down the page is giving the 2 divs a fixed height (in vh or in px), but of course the heights of my page are all different so there's usually an excess at the bottom.

Here's a simplified version on my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <header>contents here</header>
        <main>contents here</main> 
      </div>   
      <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.col-2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300vh;
}

.col-8 {
    padding: 0px;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

I've tried various solutions like using &nbsp or height: inherit but none of them work.

I just want the divs to have a background going down to the height of the page, adjusting to the contents and not having excess or white room at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.align-items-start {
  display: flex;
  /* height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.col-2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-8 {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <header>contents here</header>
        <main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos rem quas minima voluptate enim ad temporibus, eum sint ipsa dignissimos exercitationem nulla reprehenderit quidem itaque veritatis sunt sed quisquam. Magni totam harum placeat explicabo ipsa excepturi fugiat corporis, ipsam cupiditate omnis voluptates optio eveniet eligendi quo impedit cumque doloremque corrupti facere, possimus ullam error! Consequuntur recusandae reiciendis aliquam accusantium velit distinctio non, eum repellendus soluta eveniet laudantium ducimus aperiam doloremque quas libero dolores molestiae corporis ipsum exercitationem aspernatur a, quasi nisi tenetur at. Totam atque quaerat accusamus nesciunt enim quibusdam quisquam sunt maiores, vero expedita deleniti consequatur, impedit qui libero sit dignissimos neque dolores culpa nisi officiis minus magnam. Deleniti reprehenderit aliquam id. Sed, soluta. Tenetur, impedit alias repellendus provident sunt rem at veritatis iure voluptatibus autem? Fugit veritatis dicta hic, officia sequi eligendi reiciendis corrupti maiores perspiciatis architecto vitae quae voluptatum sit dolor voluptatem adipisci eius id quaerat officiis sint, repellendus magni! Pariatur reiciendis dolorem quam! Sit vel excepturi debitis? Quia ad odit voluptatibus esse quod magnam dolorum, labore voluptas tempore voluptate aspernatur maiores? At ipsam tenetur aspernatur, et obcaecati repellendus doloremque pariatur quo deserunt dolor labore dolores nostrum nam quaerat esse porro numquam nemo earum voluptatum magnam rem illum est aut. Earum eligendi placeat animi beatae et sapiente doloremque quidem illum saepe perspiciatis! Hic, quidem? Exercitationem provident harum explicabo corrupti, est suscipit commodi. Sint, ipsa quasi? Minus atque impedit quas rem assumenda eum non nesciunt, molestiae quam voluptatem aut explicabo fugiat veniam voluptate, eaque voluptates. Velit, perferendis quasi officiis veniam iusto voluptate quisquam illum reprehenderit id beatae totam in quos sed sapiente iure nam saepe provident? Minus, quibusdam! Sequi accusantium obcaecati natus minus iure optio voluptas nihil? Suscipit nobis eum eius dignissimos, in nostrum asperiores ipsa iste placeat ex porro neque, voluptate dicta itaque reiciendis sunt reprehenderit tempora modi a sint quisquam, repudiandae voluptates. Voluptatum iste similique consequatur ipsum. Exercitationem aliquam minima ipsa eius quam debitis officia minus laboriosam, quae commodi ea at nam quia blanditiis natus eos ad temporibus consectetur! Error quibusdam nobis officia quia, sunt distinctio nisi eius, nostrum perspiciatis autem maxime. Mollitia, id perferendis architecto voluptate tenetur at ad iure non facilis! Repellat, eligendi recusandae tempore harum sapiente ipsa? Et similique ipsa repellendus beatae rerum dolor repellat rem ipsam provident dolore deleniti reiciendis recusandae corporis nemo harum quisquam quidem quo incidunt minus praesentium perspiciatis fugit, vel consectetur sequi? Aliquam, fuga qui reiciendis facilis quos vero vitae deleniti autem quis, corporis nulla a dolorem? Facilis ipsum nobis magnam ducimus reiciendis voluptas veniam, earum natus a explicabo, quae corrupti sit amet obcaecati harum eligendi tempore dolorum. Maxime incidunt, placeat asperiores delectus ipsum dolore eligendi sed ea saepe aliquam fugiat nobis mollitia quae rem reprehenderit id debitis esse fuga. Sint illum rerum tempore hic repellendus ab aperiam, adipisci vel corrupti non! Odio dicta facere libero, totam qui repellat voluptatibus minus, assumenda tenetur laboriosam culpa corrupti magni accusantium obcaecati facilis iste quam deleniti consectetur sapiente voluptates excepturi itaque. Quo id repudiandae alias cum iure eligendi odit sunt a fuga.</main> 
      </div>   
      <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</body>
```

Try using `display:flex;` in the parent block `row`. Child blocks are automatically aligned to the largest.

Comment: Okay so i tried this out and at first it didn't work. So I tried inspecting the page and found out there's this instruction: 
` .align-items-start {align-items: flex-start !important;} ` 

that isn't in my CSS but appears in a sheet called _utilities.scss:71. If I remove this command in the inspector everything works perfect, but how to I actually remove that from my CSS?

Comment: Looks like you're using Bootstrap. So the problem is this.

Comment: Read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container. `The reason the items become the same height is that the initial value of align-items, the property that controls alignment on the cross axis, is set to stretch.`

Comment: You need to change `align-items: flex-start` to `align-items: stretch`.